# devexpress vb.net treelist group summary on every node level

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, summary, treelist

there. I am an in-house Vb.net programmer in one manufacturing company. It's a SME. I am upgrading COA (Chart of Account) using devexpress vb.net and to be specific, I utilise treelist component to display COA.

Unfortunately, the component doesnt summarise all nodes.

I really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

I've create one short version of my COA display VB.net code and a screenshoot of executed form.

```
Imports DevExpress.Data

Public Class Form1
    Dim DataTable1 As New DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        DataTable1.Columns.Add("NodeIDParent", GetType(String))
        DataTable1.Columns.Add("NodeID", GetType(String))
        DataTable1.Columns.Add("NodeName", GetType(String))
        DataTable1.Columns.Add("NodeValue", GetType(Integer))

        DataTable1.Rows.Add("", "01", "Node One", 0)

        DataTable1.Rows.Add("01", "03", "Node One One", 0)
        DataTable1.Rows.Add("03", "07", "Node One One One", 0)
        DataTable1.Rows.Add("07", "08", "Node One One One One", 6)
        DataTable1.Rows.Add("07", "09", "Node One One One Two", 7)
        DataTable1.Rows.Add("07", "10", "Node One One One Tree", 8)

        DataTable1.Rows.Add("01", "04", "Node One Two", 0)
        DataTable1.Rows.Add("04", "05", "Node One Two One", 2)
        DataTable1.Rows.Add("04", "06", "Node One Two Two", 5)

        DataTable1.Rows.Add("", "02", "Node Two", 0)

        With TreeList1
            .DataSource = DataTable1

            .OptionsView.ShowRowFooterSummary = True
            .Columns("NodeValue").RowFooterSummary = SummaryItemType.Sum

            .OptionsView.ShowSummaryFooter = True
            .Columns("NodeValue").SummaryFooter = SummaryItemType.Sum

            .Columns("NodeValue").AllNodesSummary = True

            .ParentFieldName = "NodeIDParent"
            .KeyFieldName = "NodeID"
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 Dim item As GridGroupSummaryItem = New GridGroupSummaryItem()
        item.FieldName = Grid.Columns("NodeValue").FieldName
        item.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum
        item.ShowInGroupColumnFooter = Grid.Columns("NodeValue")
        item.DisplayFormat = "{0:#,##0.00}"

 Grid.GroupSummary.Add(item)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, anyway, i've just tried inserting ur code, it doesnt work. Are you that GridGroupSummary? Because the component that i use is TreeList instead of Grid.